# Is there any way not to use !empty three times in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to make if statement. If an array `$list[0]`, `$list[1]` and `$list[2]` are not empty, then I have enough so that I can do with these.

```
if(!empty($list[0]) AND !empty($list[1]) AND !empty($list[2])){
// do something
}else{
// output error and redirect
}
```

Is there any other way to shorten the above if statement? Or is it good enough?

Comment: Maybe you could you use `count($list) >= 3` instead.

Comment: Are there just those three items in the list and you are testing all items in the list; or are you just testing the first three items and there could potentially be more items?

Comment: Are you just checking for `""` or also for not set values?

Comment: Not that I know anything about PHP but wouldn't it be better if you write if in if statements? like `if(!empty($list[0])){if(!empty($list[1])){if(!empty($list[0]2){//do something}} }`.Because it looks like you have priorities for that items in the list.

Comment: Are there other elements in the array?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by “not empty”?

Comment: @BoltClock well I'd love to learn why, if it is bad.

Comment: @RoboLover: because it makes code less readable while bringing no benefits.

Comment: @Mchl and no performance gain?Wouldn't it give you the chance of one or two less if controls?Any trade-off?

Comment: @RoboLover: PHP interpreter knows how to short-circuit such tests. If `!empty($list[0])` evaluates to false, the two others checks will not be performed at all.

Comment: if(!empty($list[0])) in the condition is the same as if($list[0]), both should evaluate to same result.

Comment: @Mchl Well, thanks I didn't know that, then of course what I wrote is useless.

Comment: @Mchl: Show the case, when evaluation to boolean will be wrong, please.

Comment: @Fedir: As long as the index is set, it is indeed the same. However `empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var, except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set. ` (php.net)

Comment: @Mchl Exactly, the cleanest version is : if(isset($a[0]) && $a[0])

Answer (score 6):

Keep it simple. You could probably do it in seemingly 'smarter' way, but in fact it would probably only make code less readable.

Comment: Do you mean it is ok as I wrote?

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about dealing with a general case (arrays of any length) then a foreach() that checks the elements in turn may be a better approach.

If you're dealing with a specific case where you always expect 3 elements then what you're doing is fine.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible, that, if `$list[0]` is empty, the other two are also empty? e.g. when importing with fgetcsv, this is the case. So then, one condition would fit. if not, then I would say you're doing it right.

AFAIk you can remove empty because NULL is als treated as FALSE in conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler code:

```
if(empty($list[0]) OR empty($list[1]) OR empty($list[2])){
// output error and redirect 
EXIT;
}

// do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that Empty also returns false when the value is zero.
We would need more info about what $list is about to give smarter answers.

Answer (score 0):

[isset(...)](http://docs.php.net/isset) can handle more than one parameter.
**If** isset() and empty() are interchangeable in your case ( "Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL" vs http://docs.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) you can write

```
if ( isset($list[0], $list[1], $list[2]) ) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you may wish to filter out your array first, to get rid of empty values as you probably don't want them anyway

```
$list = array_filter($list);
```

and then check if you have enough values

```
if (count($list) > 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

The code you wrote is perfectly fine, but if you're looking for an alternative.. you could do something like:

```
$none_empty = true;

foreach($list as $array) {
   if(empty($array)) {
    $none_empty = false;
    break;
   }
}

if($none_empty) {
// do something
}else{
// output error and redirect
}
```

Let me know if that works for you ;)

Comment: Why did I get a -1? is this not what the OP wasked? :(